# ESP32 Power Switch Schematic Review

Tags: mosfet, power, esp32, schematic

I'm designing a WIFI power switch using a simple circuit of an ESP32 and MOSFET. Battery will plug into IN terminal and the board that is being powered on/off will be plugged into the OUT terminal.

Can anyone find anything wrong in the schematic? I'm unsure of what caps to use on the ESP32 3v3 in line.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: A link to the data sheet for the MOSFET is definitely required. A specification of the output load range is are also definitely required. Under-voltage lock-out (to protect the MOSFET) is a likely necessity.

Comment: If the load is inductive or you have long cables then you should also consider a flywheel diode or similar to prevent power out neg from rising to a voltage that would exceed Vds max for your FET.   Stylistically I would rename VCC to VBAT.  Makes no difference but VCC is a bit misleading.

Comment: One other comment is that you may need a fairly big cap at J3, otherwise when you turn the FET on you might find the inrush current to your load will brown out VCC below a level that will keep the ESP32 running (plus the issue with the FET as mentioned by Andy aka above).

Comment: Make sure your EN and bootstrap pins follow Espressif's reference design. You will not be able to program the module in-circuit otherwise.